# Update CTE updates the underlying table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

DB Platform - MS SQL Server 2008R2
I have this table -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CaseTest](
    [SampleText] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](10) NULL
)

GO
```

Populated with sample data

```
INSERT INTO CaseTest
VALUES ('Text1',1,NULL),
('Text2',2,NULL),
('Text3',3,NULL),
('Text4',4,NULL),
('Text5',5,NULL)
```

Now when I run the following query, I really did not expect any changes to the data, but I find that the actual table data got updated.

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT * FROM casetest
)
UPDATE CTE SET Name = 'NameText'
```

Is this the expected behaviour? How does this actually happen?

Comment: Given that a CTE only exists for the single statement that follows it, and so the `UPDATE` was the only statement that could "see" this particular CTE, what did you *expect* the `UPDATE` to do in any meaningful way, if it didn't affect the underlying table?

Comment: True. However, since the CTE is just an in-memory object, I did not really expect it to do an actual update. I assumed that this would be meaningless, as the CTE will be updated and not available anymore. Guess I assumed wrong :)

Comment: A CTE *isn't* an "in-memory object" - it's a named query that can be included in a larger query - nothing is materialized (in either memory or on disk), and it's not separately optimized either.

Comment: It is expected behaviour and very useful when you want to use window functions in a `delete` or `update` statement for example to remove duplicates or populate sequential numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you yourself observe in a comment:

> I assumed that this would be meaningless

And, indeed, it would be for any of the statements that actually make changes to the database - every such operation could be optimized away as a no-op. And so, it wouldn't actually make sense in such a case to even *allow* you to write something other than a `SELECT` after creating CTEs.

But that's not the route they chose to go down - they do allow `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, etc to be written. By the same logic that they allow certain updating operations to be applied to views. Provided that the database engine can take your `UPDATE` statement and, via the CTE, can determine a single target table to `UPDATE`, the `UPDATE` via the CTE will be allowed.

---

> since the CTE is just an in-memory object

It's not. It's just a named query, nothing is materialized when the CTE is written. Effectively, the CTE is inserted into the final query that uses it (in as many places as it's referenced) and then the entire query is optimized and executed.

The database engine *may* decide, at the point of optimizing the final query, to materialize some or all of the CTE into storage (via it's Spool operators) but that's an optimization decision that occurs later - and one that the engine is equally capable of deciding to use even for simple, non-CTE queries.